# pass global variable into jquery function

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a highchart script creating a graph from 2 external .csv files.
(this part is all working well).
I'm trying to create a list that will load a different graph using a separate set of files. End result will be a list of filesets on the left, as you click each one, it is plotted.
Despite setting file1,file2 as global variables, I can't seem to get them back into the main() function. Ie, no new graph loads, the original remains.
I've tried calling main() from the choose() function, but it says it's not defined.
I'm not sure what to do.

```
<head><script>
var file1 = 'file1.csv'
var file2 = 'file2.csv'
function choose(choice,choice2,){file1 = choice;file2 = choice2}

$(function main() {
    $.get(file1, function(csv) {
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
....etc
</script></head>

<body><div>
<li><a id="1" onClick="choose('file1.csv','file2.csv')">FileSet1</a></li>
<li><a id="2" onClick="choose('file3.csv','file4.csv')">FileSet2</a></li>
```

Comment: wrap the ajax in a function...call that function on pageload and inside `choose`. Personally I would get rid of `onclick` and handle everything with jQuery and therefore get rid of globals and put all in the `main` closure

Comment: `choose` sets the variables, but it doesn't redraw the chart.

Comment: Thanks so much charlietfl, managed to get it to work. Any advice on how to replace the onclick with jquery? I'm trying something like http://jsfiddle.net/kzVSt/ but not confident about what I'm doing.

Comment: Other way would be to use `.on( "click", handler )` Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzVSt/292/ More info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in one string in the event handlers. What do you expect when you o this?

```
var str = 'file1.csv,file2.csv';
alert(str);
```

You need to add quotes

```
onClick="choose('file1.csv', 'file2.csv')"
```

Now the orginal code with the Highcharts is not going to magically run since you change the value. You would need to call a function and have it run the code again.

Comment: Apologies epascarello, I incorrectly transcribed the code when asking the question, i have the quotations correctly in my code.

Comment: Well the second part is still valid, the main does not rerun when the variables are updated. You need to call the function again to fetch the data.